# handling form using POST

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm working on a form and form handler. Method is `_POST` and I handle it using **PHP**. Now , When I wanna Handle The Form , it said `$username` is undefined.

**My Form :**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/register_form_validator.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="includes/register_form_handler.php" name="register_form" >
      <label for="username" >Username :</label><input placeholder="username" type="text" /><br>
      <label for="password">Password :</label><input type="password" name="password" /><br>
      <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password :</label><input type="password" name="cpassword" /><br>
      <label for="email">E-Mail :</label><input type="email" name="email" onChange="" /><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**handler :**

```
<?php
// Do a Form Validation , Makes sure that resource is Valid///////////
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]" . "/dcreview/register.php";
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  echo "Invalid Form";
  exit;
} else {
  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != $actual_link) {
    echo "Invalid Form";
    exit;
  }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Processes Form //
$user = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
?>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to mention `$username`, so your error doesn't match?

Comment: `$user` != `$username` Your script defines `$user`

Comment: Thanks People to Answer . I think I should Look At my codes twice and more. It was mistake of my eye .sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your Username HTML with this line

```
<label for="username" >Username :</label><input name="username" placeholder="username" type="text"  /><br>
```

Comment: Explain what you changed!

Comment: I added name="username" in your input tag which was missing to check in $_POST['username'];

Answer (score 3):

Your username doesn't have a name attribute. Use this:

```
<input name="username" placeholder="username" type="text" />
```